# how can i use xpath to grab content from a curl response -- Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, curl, xpath

okay so i have the source code from a website i am trying to grab this info 0.00 from the following source code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span10">
<div id="conn_status"/><br/>
<div id="balance_notifications"/>





</div>
</div>



<center>



<h2>0 RLM
(0.00 USD)</h2>
```

i want to be able to grab both the 0 RLM value the 0 does change 
and i also want to grab the 0.00 usd part i only need the numbers to display in echo output in my php file

here what i have so far

```
<?php
   function check($url2){
    $check = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($check, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookiemon.txt');
    curl_setopt($check, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookiemon.txt');
    curl_setopt($check, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($check, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($check, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
    curl_setopt($check, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($check, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
return curl_exec ($check);
curl_close ($check);


} 
$html = check('https://example.org/');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$value = $xpath->query('//label[@id="balance_notifications"]/following-sibling::text()')->item(0)->nodeValue;
?>
```

and this is the php response i get

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/newphp.php on line 20

Comment: Your XPath contains multiple very basic problems. To get a better understanding, I strongly recommend you to fetch some XPath tutorial and work through it.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression is wrong, that's why there is non first element (there is none at all).

If this is the only `<h2/>` element in your content, use `//h2` as XPath expression.

If you want to query the first one after the `<div id="balance_notifications"/>`, you could use this expression (and others, but you're not giving enough information on your input):

```
//div[@class="row"][.//div[@id="balance_notifications"]]//h2
```

If you cannot rely on having that `<div class="row"/>`, use `following::h2` and limit to the first result:

```
//div[@id="balance_notifications"]/following::h2[1]
```

---

Regarding the string manipulation: XPath 1.0 which you're using in PHP cannot do that, so you've got to split it up in PHP.

Comment: thanks for the reply i have struggled getting it to work with your answer is there any other suggestions u can give me to get the 0.00 value and the 0 value and have php echo the result

Comment: Read about how to provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). You will not get any better answers without making others able to reproduce your problem. And tell us _exactly_ where you're stuck at. Paying some attention to capitalization and punctuation would make your question much easier to understand.